# Matlab GUI, Slider with char output

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider, serial-port, matlab-guide

I want to make a GUI have a slider, this slider's value will be used to transmit serial data to PIC microcontroller.

The output value of the slider must be a character or string.

1. How can I define enter code here variable in matlab gui?
2. How can I know the type of output value of slider ? (int, char, ...)

code:

```
s=serial('COM7');
slider_value = get(handles.slider3, 'value');
fopen(s);
fprintf(s,'%s',slider_value);
fclose(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful information: http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html.

The type of the `Value` property is the scalar value it currently has. This value will between `Min` and `Max` which defaults to 0 and 1, respectively. Did you set these to other values? The scalar value will likely be in double representation so you need to convert to a string:

Put this in your init-section (a slider that goes from 0 to 100):

```
set(handles.slider3, 'Min', 0); %set min to 0 (default)
set(handles.slider3, 'Max', 100); %set min to 100 (default)
set(handles.slider3, 'SliderStep', [1 10]);
```

And this in your callback routine:

```
s = serial('COM7');
slider_value = get(handles.slider3, 'Value');
fopen(s);
fprintf(s, '%u', uint32(slider_value));
fclose(s)
```

The above is just an example. You should set `Min`, `Max`, and `SliderStep` to what you want. Find the relevant sections in the UIcontrol properties documentation that I link to in the beginning. You should also note that I send the data as an unsigned 32-bit value (not the recast).

Comment: but should i convert the data to char in order to send it serially ?

Comment: The conversion to char array (string type in MATLAB) is being by the `fprintf` function. I used the pattern `'%u'` to format the 32-bit unsigned integer. I used `uint32` to allow as large a range as possible. In this specific example, with a range from 0 to 100 you could also have used `uint16` or `uint8`.

Answer (score 0):

In general the output value of the slider will have the type of int.  I would expect an int because of the nature of a slider in which you're sliding along increasing/decreasing numbers of some sort.

You can also use the 'class()' function in matlab to determine the class of a variable.

In addition, you can make the slider give you whatever output you need by specifying it in the callback routine for the slider.